# HTML mail rejecting because of unexpected content type

Tags: html, email, mailgun

I ran a small test (three messages) of sending HTML email.  All three rejected with the following:

```
{\n  "message": "Invalid request content type. Expecting \'multipart/form-data\' but got \'application/x-www-form-urlencoded\' instead."\n}
```

I'm new at this, so I'm sure I've done something incorrectly but I don't know what to fix.  It seems likely it's to do with my meta tag regarding content.  Here is the HTML I used for my test message:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>Efani SIM Protect</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
 </head>
 <table align="left" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
  <tr>
   <td style="font-size: 0; line-height: 0;" height="10">
    This is a test of the email blaster's capabilities.
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <a href="https://efani.com/?ref=11&campaign=JohnCrockett">Hello world!  I am an anchor tag!</a>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</html>
```

Here is the relevant (I think) part of my code:

```
    def send_message(sender, subject, body_text, body_html, recipient):
    return requests.post(
        "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/mg001.simdefense.com/messages.mime",
        auth=("api", "MY_API_KEY"),
        data={"from": sender,
              "to": recipient,
              "subject": subject,
              "text": body_text,
              "html": body_html})
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction, I would be grateful.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the HTML. The problem is with the code you are using to communicate with the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your header, make sure you specify multipart/form-data encoding. Per mailgun's api docs: "You must use multipart/form-data encoding". Try that and let us know if it works! :) good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your help!  I'm not sure what you mean by "In your header."  I thought Mailgun built the email header from the info I provided.  Where would I specify "multipart/data-encoding?"  I'm adding the part of my code (python) that actually makes a connection to the API, above, in my original question.

Comment: No worries! Which library are you using? (e.g., ruby, java, .net, Node.js, php, python, etc)

Comment: after your data you can include a headers={ } argument where you can specify 'Content-Type'

Comment: Ah.  THANK YOU!  I'll try that and report back.

Comment: I can't find any documentation about using the "headers={ }" argument, so I'm firing blind.  I tried " headers={"content type": "multipart/form-data"} " but I still get the same error message.  Maybe I should clarify...I've been a programmer all my life (4+ decades), it's trying to talk to Mailgun's API and formatting HTML emails that I'm new to.

Comment: oops.  Just realized you have a hyphen in there...let me try again.

Comment: headers={"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"} works.
Now there's a new problem, but I'll keep researching and if I can't find an answer, I'll start a new question.
Thank you again, for your help!